# How to grant folder access after login?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

This is my folder structure:

```
/+---home
 +---public
```

My node.js entry point resides in the "public" folder (i.e. public/server.js).

My requirement is that all users must be login before they can access the "home" folder.
The login form is stored in public/index.html file.

For testing purpose, I put an index.html in "home" folder.

Unfortunately, I got nothing after I login.

[image]

Would you tell me what is the problem?

This is my login form(i.e. public/index.html).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Chat Room</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/login">
            Nick name/Alias:<input type=text required name="alias"><br>
            Email Address:<input type=email required name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my server.js code:

```
var bodyParse = require('body-parser')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
var userList={};

var http = require('http');
var serverPort = 81;
server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at %s port', serverPort);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParse.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.post('/login', function(request, response) {

    var alias = request.body.alias;
    var email = request.body.email;

    if (userList[email]==null) {
        request.session.loggedin = true;
        request.session.alias=alias;
        request.session.email=email;
        response.redirect('/home');
    } else {
        response.send("<script>alert('Your email address has been used, please use anothe one.');location.href='/';</script>");
    }   
});
app.all('/home', function(request, response,next) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        next();
    } else {
        response.send("<script>alert('Your have to login to view this page.');location.href='/';</script>");
    }
    response.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I solve the problem by using the express render method.